# Algorithm to check overlap between arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have two arrays, one of existing appointments and one of potential appointments.  The arrays each contain from/to values of the existing or potential appointments. The appointments in each array are already sorted by the from time.

I need to check each of the potential appointments against each of the existing appointments to see that there is no overlap. I know I can start from the beginning of the existing appointments each time but I am looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: For what programming language?

Answer (score 1):

The idea: start comparing the first intervals to each other. If one interval comes entirely before the other, look at the next interval until you find one that overlaps or comes after. Either interval A comes entirely before interval B, or B comes entirely before A, or they overlap somehow. Once you find an overlap, you can quit looking. This can be made to easily return the earliest overlapping pair, but returning all overlapping pairs would require more work.

Pseudocode:

```
Overlaps(actual[1..n], pending[1..m])
    i = 1
    j = 1
    while i <= n and j <= m do
        if actual[i].stop <= pending[j].start then
            i = i + 1
        else if actual[i].start >= pending[j].stop then
            j = j + 1
        else
            return true
    return false
```

Note - if you want to find all overlapping pairs, instead of quitting after detecting the first overlap, you could just print out `i` and `j` and increment `i` if `actual[i].stop <= pending[j].stop` or increment `j` if `actual[i].stop > pending[j].stop`. That would end up printing every overlapping pair and is still linear time.

Comment: the problem is what you do when you find an overlap, because ALL potential appointments need to be checked and the idea is not to go back to the start to check again for the next potential appointment

Comment: @user1480192 You want a method that will return *all* overlapping pairs of appointments? Or just one that says "you have overlapping appointments". Mine answers the latter question correctly. Or are you saying this isn't efficient enough? Since everything's sorted it might be possible to use some kind of binary search or something - I'll think it over.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done efficiently in O(nlogn). Consider two arrays `A, B` containing existing and potential appointments respectively. Sort `A` in increasing order of ending times of appointments (`A_end`) and starting time of appointments (`A_start`). This takes O(nlogn) time

For each potential appointment in `B`:
s = starting point of the assignment
t = ending point of the assignment

Now, binary search on array `A_start` and `A_end` to find all the appointments that fall between s-t taking o(logn) time.
[# Overlaps =
(appointments with ending time <= t) - (appointments with ending time < s) +
(appointments with ending time > t) -  (appointments with starting time > t) +
]

Thus, overall order is O(nlogn)

**EDIT**: #overlaps = sum_1 + sum_2
Here sum_1 represents those intervals with ending time <= t. But again to only find the overlapping intervals we have to subtract those intervals with ending time < s. Thus, we get only those with ending time >=s and <=t.
Here sum_2 represents those intervals with ending time > t. But again to only find the overlapping intervals we have to subtract those intervals with ending time > t. Thus we get only those with ending time >t but starting time <=t.

Proof can be given by the fact that any overlapping interval can either have ending time <=t or >t. Thus it will either lie in sum_1 or sum_2.

Comment: Incorrect, as you can't use binary search this way. Array `A` is only sorted by endtime, the start times can be in any order. Suppose all intervals in `A` end after `s`, but only the very last interval in `A` starts before `t`. Then, you need to check all elements of `A` to find the overlapping inteval.

Comment: @BKE check the edit section. I don't assume we have to find the actual overlapping, because it can't be done in less that O(n^2) as it may happen that all intervals overlaps. This algorithm is just to count the #overlaps.

Comment: It is correct now that you sort both by starting time and ending time. Note, you do not need to calculate (appointments with ending time <= t) as the sum of the two first terms is the number of appointments. So you can just count the non-overlapping intervals and subtract it from the length of the array, and save one binary search.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the union of the the existing and potential appointments into a single array, and sort the union by start time. Add a label to the intervals so you know it was an existing or a potential interval. (You can also sort them in separate arrays and increment two indices, but the code is simpler with one list).

You can then loop through the combined array, and merge together neighboring intervals if they overlap. Only merge existing appointments with existing, and likewise, potential appointments with potential. For this, you have to memorize the most recent existing and potential intervals.

This way, you do not need to go back to the very beginning, you only need to look at the most recently merged intervals.

In psedudocode:

```
E: existing appointments
P: potential appointments

A: union of P and E, sorted by start time

lastE = []
lastP = []
for each appointment a in A:
    if a is existing:
        if a overlaps with lastE:
            lastE = lastE + [a]
        else
            lastE = [a]
        if a overlaps with lastP:
            print all appointments in lastP overlapping with a
    if a is potential:
        if a overlaps with lastE:
            print a
        if a overlaps with lastP:
            lastP = lastP + [a]
        else:
            lastP = [a]
```

Note, that you need not store the structure of `lastE`, you can define it as a single interval and adjust the start and end time.

You need to know the individual appointments in `lastP` though. You can possibly optimize it even further by maintaining a descending order by end time in `lastP`. Then, on the line when all overlaps between `a` and `lastP` are printed, you can stop looking once the end time of the potential appointment in `lastP` is smaller than the start time of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

if we first join these two arrays and the time required for joining is O(n) and then we sort the whole array and this sorting required O(nlogn) if we use quick sort or merge sort then if we compute the total time complexity, it will be like this

F(n) = O(n) + O(nlogn)

so final complexity will be O(nlogn) which is laser than O(n^2)